# Selenium Java Xpath complex element determination of child of one sibling

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate a specific element on a page but cannot figure out the proper Xpath to use.

Here is the HTML (note that the location of each div can vary):

```
    <div>
     <label>First Name</label>
     <span class="metadataField metadataFieldReadonly">
      <input type="text" name="some-random-value" value="John">
     </span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <label>Last Name</label>
     <span class="metadataField metadataFieldReadonly">
      <input type="text" name="some-random-value" value="Smith">
     </span>
    </div>
```

So what I am trying to locate the INPUT element that is the //div/span[@class='metadataField metadataFieldReadonly']/input in the same div that has a //div/label[text()='Last Name']

I can successfully locate the label with this (using JAVA):

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/label[text()='Last Name']")).click();
```

And I can successfully locate the first input under the first element (but I may not always want the first element) with this:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/span[@class='metadataField metadataFieldReadonly']/input")).click();
```

So the problems are that (i) the name tag and value of the INPUT are always different so they cannot be used to pick the element, and (ii) the div with the last name label may not always be the second one, and (iii) the label and span are the same level (siblings) so I cannot figure out how to properly create the Xpath statement.

So in words, I need to find the input of the span in the same div that has a label with 'Last Name' in it.

So I need to know how to combine these two XPath statements into one complex statement (assuming they are in the same div and that the label and span are siblings):

```
    //div/label[text()='Last Name']
    //div/span[@class='metadataField metadataFieldReadonly']/input
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's downright easy: `//div[label[text()='Last Name']]/span[@class='metadataField metadataFieldReadonly']/input` - literally, "*the `input` contained in the `span` with the `metadataField` and `metadataFieldReadonly` classes contained in the `div` that contains the `label` with the text 'Last Name'*".  So you're using the label to locate the div and then building from it to the input you want.

To be a more robust, you shouldn't count on the ordering of the class names - that isn't guaranteed by the specs.  So something like this would be stronger: `//div[label[text()='Last Name']]/span[contains(concat(' ', @class,' '),' metadataField ') and contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' metadataFieldReadonly ')]/input`.

Comment: It's downright easy now that I see how to do it lol !!! I can see now how you used the square brackets around the label to pick a specific div... this was what I could not figure out! Accepted as correct answer. Thanks

Comment: And +1 for the additional info on class names ordering :)

Comment: The "_square brackets around the label to pick a specific div_" works because what most folks think of as a place to check an attribute value is actually a very powerful conditional expression model.  Go forth and conquer :-)